# Can a view controller own a sheet?

Tags: macos, cocoa, controller, cocoa-sheet

I want to call a sheet from within a view controller (user clicks on a button and the sheet will be displayed). Can the sheet have a separate window controller (with outlets and actions) or does the view controller from which the sheet is called operate as the sheet's controller?

I'm trying to determine how to display a sheet from a separate Interface Builder (.xib) file than my view controller. The sheet will have a list based on a popup menu item, so I would like to put that "logic" in a separate controller. I tried using a `NSWindowController`, but that didn't work.

Comment: What programming language? And please post some code/try to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, using Cocoa OSX. I'm trying to determine how to display a sheet from a separate xib file than my view controller. The sheet will have a list based on a popup menu item, so would like to put that "logic" in a separate controller. Tried using a NSWindowController, but that didn't work.

Comment: What is with all the close votes lately? How is this “not a real question”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stock NSViewController controls a view; nothing more. You can make a custom subclass that owns  the sheet, or you can make it own a window controller which owns the sheet. The choice is yours.

> Tried using a NSWindowController, but that didn't work.

You should ask another question about that.

Comment: Peter, Thank you for the input. I made a subclass of NSPanel (owner of the sheet) which I call from my view controller. That seems to be working. I really appreciate the feedback. - Scott

Comment: @Scott: An NSPanel is a subclass of window. A sheet is one way to deploy a window (especially a panel). A window should not own another window. You should replace the NSPanel with an NSWindowController.